# WP - Add New User Form

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm creating a plugin where I'm wanting the owner of the company to be able to log in and be able to add employees/contractors and upon creating them, have them added to the wpdb. Right now, I've copied over the the html that was in the source code for the Add New User (I don't want to use the add new user format) and I've got the form there (minus what I'm guessing is the ajax and javascript bits). When I click submit it just returns to the page.

Here is the code that is being called in... I'm wondering if I'm missing some includes or something along those lines, thanks in advance! :)

```
<?php
function e34s_tc_add_staff() 
{
global $wbdb;

    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
    <?php screen_icon(); ?>
    <h2 id="add-new-user"> Add New Staff Member</h2>

    <div id="ajax-response"></div>

    <p>Create a new staff member for this site.</p>
    <form action="" method="post" name="createuser" id="createuser" class="validate">
    <input name="action" type="hidden" value="createuser" />
    <input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce_create-user" name="_wpnonce_create-user" value="5ebe2973f8" /><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/wordpress/wp-admin/user-new.php" /><table class="form-table">
    <tr class="form-field form-required">
        <th scope="row"><label for="user_login">Username <span class="description">(required)</span></label></th>
        <td><input name="user_login" type="text" id="user_login" value="" aria-required="true" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field form-required">
        <th scope="row"><label for="email">E-mail <span class="description">(required)</span></label></th>
        <td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row"><label for="first_name">First Name </label></th>
        <td><input name="first_name" type="text" id="first_name" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row"><label for="last_name">Last Name </label></th>
        <td><input name="last_name" type="text" id="last_name" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field form-required">
        <th scope="row"><label for="pass1">Password <span class="description">(required)</span></label></th>
        <td>
            <input class="hidden" value=" " /><!-- #24364 workaround -->
            <input name="pass1" type="password" id="pass1" autocomplete="off" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field form-required">
        <th scope="row"><label for="pass2">Repeat Password <span class="description">(required)</span></label></th>
        <td>
        <input name="pass2" type="password" id="pass2" autocomplete="off" />
        <br />
        <div id="pass-strength-result">Strength indicator</div>
        <p class="description indicator-hint">Hint: The password should be at least seven characters long. To make it stronger, use upper and lower case letters, numbers and symbols like ! " ? $ % ^ &amp; ).</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"><label for="send_password">Send Password?</label></th>
        <td><label for="send_password"><input type="checkbox" name="send_password" id="send_password"  /> Send this password to the new user by email.</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row"><label for="role">Staff Type</label></th>
        <td><select name="role" id="role">

    <option value='employee'>Employee</option>        
    <option value='contractor'>Contractor</option>
    </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>


<p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="createuser" id="createusersub" class="button button-primary" value="Add New Staff Member "  /></p>
</form>
</div>
<?php
}
```

Comment: I'm also wanting this to be creating a separate db named after the username. I haven't started coding this, I know I can find the answers to have it do this but if anyone has a quick solution for that as well, I'd welcome it :)

Comment: Wheres your php / mysql code?

Comment: Well lookie there, this code is pretty much straight over from wp's add new user, as I mentioned... appears the action="" is blank... I have no idear what it's posting to then...

Comment: A blank or missing `action` attribute will result in the form being submitted to the current URL.

Comment: I was able to throw in the url to the user-new.php which was a built in php file in wp.... that worked just fine...